# PHP syntaxエラー

Tags: php

以下のコードについて質問です。

エラーが表示されてしまいますが、`{}` か `$` でどこかで定義しなければいけないのだと思いますが、どこをどうすれば良いのかわかりません。

よろしくお願いします。

---

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"a"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /contact_send.php on line 24
```

**ソースコード:**

```php
<?
if(empty($_POST))
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit();
}

$subject = "講座お申し込み完了";
$body = "講座のお申し込みを受け付けました。\n\n" .
    
                "内容：{$_POST['entryPlan']}\n" .
                "会社名：{$_POST['company']}\n" .
                "お名前：{$_POST['fname']} {$_POST['lname']}\n" .
                "メールアドレス:{$_POST['email']}\n";

mb_send_mail($_POST['your-email'], $subject, $body, "From: info@○○○○.jp");
// mb_send_mail("info@○○○○.jp", $subject, $body, "From: info@○○○○.jp");

// 講座に登録するユーザーリストに登録
function register_mail_newsletter_list($email, $date, $no, $status = 0)
{
$url = "https://○○○○.com/stepmail/kd.php?no={$no}";

if (($_POST['entryPlan'])->"a")
    {
        $no = 'A';
    }
else ($_POST['entryPlan'->'b'])
    {
        $no = 'B';
    }
$data = array
(
        "registration_mail" => $email,
        "action" => "confirm",
        "no" => $no,
);

$options = array("http" => array
(
        "method" => "POST",
        "content" => http_build_query($data),
));
file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($options));
}

header("Location: thanks.html");
?>
```

Comment: PHP は詳しくないので直接の回答はできませんが、続く `else` の行とは `( )` の中で記述方法が微妙に違っているようなので、この辺りを確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 編集頂きありがとうございます。
確かに記述方法が違っていました。
ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

エラーメッセージにある`line 24`はこの行のことでしょう。

```
if (($_POST['entryPlan'])->"a")
```

`->`という記号にどのような意味を期待して使用されているのかわかりませんが、そこは

```
if ($_POST['entryPlan'] === "a")
```

とでもすべきところではないでしょうか?

上記を修正しても続く28行目:

```
else ($_POST['entryPlan'->'b'])
```

この行もPHPのコードとして、

- `else`の後に条件式と思われる`(...)`がある
- `$_POST`への添字として、`'entryPlan'->'b'`と言うPHP的には意味のない式を使っている

などの問題点があります。

```
else if( $_POST['entryPlan'] === 'b' )
```

としたかったところではないのでしょうか?

---

上記の私の推定が正しかったとしても、「`$_POST['entryPlan']`の値が`'a'`でも`'b'`でもなかったらどうするんだ」というロジック上の問題が存在します。

また、関数として定義している`register_mail_newsletter_list`はどこからも呼び出されていませんので、構文エラーを修正しても所望の動作にはならないように思いますが、一体何をさせたくて現在のようなコードになっているかご説明いただかないと、これ以上のことは何も言えないです。

Comment: ご回答頂きありがとうございます。

やりたいことは、申し込み内容によって判別を行いたいとかんがえております。
aと申し込まれたら、Aと判別し、A用のメルマガを配信し、
bと申し込まれたら、Bと判別しBようのメルマガを配信する条件分岐を作りたいと思っています。

ご指摘頂いたように、->を===に変更したところ、
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /contact_send.php on line 30というエラーに変わりましたので、30行目の$no = 'B';の;を外したところ、
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE) in /contact_send.php on line 32というエラー文に変わりました。

Comment: @STCK さん、「Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /contact_send.php on line 30というエラーに変わりました」については、こちらの環境では再現ができません。回答中では「->を===に変更」ではない変更も書いてあるのですが、本当に書かれている内容通りに変更していただいているでしょうか? 24行目と28行目が回答に書かれた内容になっているか、再度ご確認いただけないでしょうか?

Comment: 大変失礼致しました。else ifではなく、elseのままでした。こちらをelse ifに変更したところ、解決しました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @STCK さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。PHPの構文エラーは問題点のある行とは全然別の行を指し示すことも多く、慣れるまでは、エラーメッセージを頼りに解決するのは難しいかもしれません。ご自身で解決できない事柄があれば、また遠慮せずにご質問ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。未経験からいきなりPHPを扱っているので、わからないこと大変が多く悪戦苦闘しています。初めて質問させて頂きましたが、解決できて良かったです。